# ObservableCollection + ResourceDictionnary + Listbox PropertyChanged does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, calendar

I realize my own Calendar. 
I did a Generic.xaml (ResourceDictionnary) which contains my new control. I have a Calendar.class who implement :Control.

In my Calendar class I have a `ObservableCollection<Day> _days`. I put DataContext = this;

A Day contains my `ObservableCollection<MyObject> ListeTache`. 
And Day.Class Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have my event :

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

But when I update my Listbox, I have to reload my calendar manually to see any changes.
Am I missing something ?

Thank you for the help.

My `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` :

```
public ObservableCollection<Tache> ListeTache
{
    get { return this._listeTache; }
    set
    {
        _listeTache = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListeTache"));
        }
    }
}
```

My Generic.xaml look like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutTache">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListeTaches" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeTache,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="10" PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDownClick_clear" MouseDoubleClick="doubleClic" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding AffichageCalendrier}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="MonMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Supprimer" Click="MonMenuDel_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AntiqueWhite"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MonMenu}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

---

After somme reply :

How I can do that ? I have to add something like this in my Day.cs class :

```
 _listeTache.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_listeTache_CollectionChanged);

void _listeTache_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

I never catch the event...

Thanks for all

Comment: I think your `Tache` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as you make changes to the `Tache` object and that what needs to notify UI.

Comment: Ok, i can try but I just add or remove a Tache in ObservableCollection<Tache>, I dont change a Tache itself.

Comment: Sorry didn't look at your code properly and you are right your `Tache` class doesn't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, one thing though have you tried removing that null check for your `PropertyChanged` in `Listtache`?

Comment: When I remove it, I catch TargetInvocationException.

Answer (score 1):

When designing a custom control, it is customary *not* to set the `DataContext` to `this`... in fact, don't set it to anything as this enables it to be set from outside the control. Instead, you should reference your property from `generic.xaml` using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListeTaches" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeTache, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:Calendar}}}" ... />
```

It should also be noted that using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay` on an `ItemsSource Binding` is pointless as the `ItemsControl` cannot update the source collection.

If you still can't access the property, then you must either ensure that you correctly implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `Calendar.cs`, or you can implement your `ListeTaches` property as a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

---

UPDATE >>>

You've clearly done something wrong... it's *really* not that complicated. Follow the links that I provided to declare a `DependencyProperty` in your `Calendar.cs` class. Do *not* set the `DataContext`. Use the `RelativeSource Binding` that I showed you, correctly setting up the proper XAML Namespace... that's it!

Just one last thing... you *did* add a WPF Custom Control Library project into your application, didn't you? You need to have something like this in your `Calendar` class' `static` constructor:

```
static Calendar()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Calendar), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Calendar)));
}
```

Perhaps it would help if you read through the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN to ensure that you are doing it correctly?

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

Ok, so after noticing something in your comments, I think that I know what your problem is. @XAMlMAX asked you

> have you tried removing that null check for your PropertyChanged in Listtache?

You replied

> When I remove it, I catch TargetInvocationException.

I think that that's your problem... that means that your `PropertyChanged` event is `null`... that means that you have *not* attached a handler to it yet... it's not being used. Try attaching a handler to it and your `ListeTache` collection should display fine.

Comment: Thanks, If i add RelativeSource to my Xaml, my ListBoxItem dont bind in my calendar. Nothing happened.

Comment: Read my last paragraph again.

Comment: If I remove DataContext, My Calendar dont load. I try what you said... Maybe I can force Reload in Generic.xaml.cs Code behind ?

Comment: I've already have my static constructor since the beginning. I have 4 propriety in my Day.cs witch fire event perfectely. It's just with my ObservableList<tache> that fail...

Comment: How I can do that ? I have to add something like this : _listeTache.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_listeTache_CollectionChanged);